# To split one row into two rows using one liner regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

I am using Rad tool (using .NET framework) and XML for parsing data file.

I am stuck with a particular row that has to be split into two.
The format is: (# and afterwards is just to convey column and data)

```
Drive Name     UNE   Con   Accessible by  Drive status    # column names
A L D     0    A,B         Storage Subsystem  Optimal     # Data row 1         
1         1    A           Storage Subsystem  Optimal     # Data row 2
```

The first row:

```
A L D     0    A,B         Storage Subsystem  Optimal
```

Needs to be split in two rows in the format:

```
       A L D     0    A         Storage Subsystem  Optimal
       A L D     0    B         Storage Subsystem  Optimal
```

So that the one liner RE show the extracted data in the format:-

```
Drive Name   UNE  Con   Accessible by      Drive status
A L D        0    A     Storage Subsystem  Optimal
A L D        0    B     Storage Subsystem  Optimal
1            1    A     Storage Subsystem  Optimal
```

Comment: This isn't a regex problem; you need to parse your rows and generate the 'extra' rows "by hand".

Comment: A solution or a near approach for one liner RE is highly appreciated for the mentioned issued. Since the file contain this format and so it can't be changed.

Comment: This isn't a regex problem. You cannot solve the problem with regex. As mentioned, this isn't a problem for regex.

Answer (score 2):

Expecting tab as a delimiter between 2 columns.

```
$string =~ s/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\t([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)\t(([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+),([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+))\t([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)\t([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)/$1\t$2\t$4\t$6\t$7\n$1\t$2\t$5\t$6\t$7/gs
```